# Zend Framework using built in PHP server?

Tags: php

I am trying to connect to MSSQL Server.

Does Zend have its own server or does it under Apache server in XAMP?

Answer (score 1):

Zend is a company.

There is such a thing as Zend Server.

If however you mean the Zend Framework, then yes it must run on a Web Server, be it Apache, NginX, or Zend Server.

Comment: I understand but when I run composer server it syas accroddind to the doc This will start the PHP cli-server on port 8080, and bind it to all network interfaces. https://framework.zend.com/downloads/skeleton-app

Comment: ah ok, the built in PHP server. Not recommended other than for quick and dirty dev work, but ive never actually seen the server started using composer before.  Giving us the output of that command would help

Comment: Did you mean "There is no such thing as Zend Server"?

Comment: No, I'm saying there is Zend Framework, and there is also Zend Server, and his question wasn't the clearest.